# Issue with quotes PHP/HTML output

Tags: php, html

I'm having a problem with outputting HTML in a PHP echo, I can't work out what's wrong with my quotes.

```
echo '<tr><td>' . $row[1] . '</td><td>' . $row[2] . '</td><td>' . $row[3] . '</td><td><input type=\"button\" class=\"button-link\" value=\"Create\" onClick=\"location.href="fyp.comeze.com/createassignment.php?module_id=\"' . row[2] . "\''/></td><td><input type=\"button\" class=\"button-link\" value = \"Edit\" onClick=\"\" /></td><td><input type=\"button\" class=\"button-link\" value = \"PDF\" onClick=\"\" /></td></tr>';
```

This is my error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in \public_html\FYP\modules.php on line 24
```

Any help or assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should just use double quotes around the whole string and use `{$row[1]}` syntax. Or take a look at heredoc syntax. All those string concatenations are a nightmare for maintainability - as your issue shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be having 2 problems here

The second occurrence of $row[2]  is missing it's $ prefix.
Next to that, you appear you be escaping your HTML as if you were using double quotes, which you are not.

Try the following:

```
echo 
'<tr>',
    '<td>', $row[1], '</td>',
    '<td>', $row[2], '</td>',
    '<td>', $row[3], '</td>',
    '<td>',
        '<input type="button" class="button-link" value="Create" onClick="location.href=\"fyp.comeze.com/createassignment.php?module_id=', $row[2], '\"" />',
    '</td>',
    '<td>',
        '<input type="button" class="button-link" value="Edit" onClick="" />',
    '</td>',
    '<td>',
        '<input type="button" class="button-link" value="PDF" onClick="" />',
    '</td>',
'</tr>';
```

Comment: This is a clean way to output this, if he is just wanting to echo it to the page. I'm afraid this might call the echo command individually for each comma delimited item, though. It's probably at least as fast as string concatenation. Maybe faster?

Comment: I had to actually replace the commas in the first 3 <td>'s with dots for concatenation. That fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `$` on your second reference to `row[2]`. Should be `$row[2]`.

Comment: His quotes are also messed up there. `=\"' . row[2] . "\''`

Comment: Also, if/when that does actually echo, he's going to end up with an HTML tag like: `<input type="button" class="button-link" value="Create" onClick="location.href="fyp.comeze.com/createassignment.php?module_id=something_here" />` Which is obviously another issue.

Comment: I fixed this, long day... thanks. I've also fixed the link by removing the JS.

Answer (score 0):

This code should fix your quote problems..

```
echo '<tr><td>' . $row[1] . '</td><td>' . $row[2] . '</td><td>' . $row[3] . '</td>
<td><input type="button" class="button-link" value="Create" onClick="location.href="fyp.comeze.com/createassignment.php?module_id="' . $row[2] . '"></td>
<td><input type="button" class="button-link" value = "Edit" onClick="" /></td><td><input type="button" class="button-link" value = "PDF" onClick="" /></td></tr>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the escape characters you put in for attributes of the HTML elements. These are not necessary if you are enclosing the entire string in single quotes.

So for example, `class=\"button-link\"` should probably be `'class="button-link"';`

Comment: While they aren't necessary, this isn't the source of the problem.

Comment: I am pretty sure attributes need to be surrounded in double quotes... 0_o :D

Comment: A) I never said that they didn't. I was talking about the escaping being unnecessary B) No, attributes don't need to be surrounded by double quotes. They can in fact be surrounded by single quotes, or no quotes at all.

Comment: I fixed the quotes issue. Thanks.

Comment: welcome, thanks for the learning opportunity. @crush is correct no quotes or single quotes will work for attributes I guess. I tried an `<img src=pic.png />` statement on my computer and it works for instance. :D ( I also tried it with single quotes and this also works) huzzah. In tutorials attributes always have double quotations marks. Living and Learning here... :D